# Google Maps showing invalid error key message even though the application works ok

Tags: maps, key

I have just updated my web site to include a page which includes some functionality using Google Maps, see here http://twenty20investments.com/Research/ETFMarketMap.aspx.

Although I have generated the key in all manner of ways and combinations, when I click on this link I get the message that one needs to get a different Google Maps API key.  However, the maps application works fine and does not show this error again, that is until one next clicks the link.

When generating my key should I be creating a Server or a Browser key?

Key for browser apps (with referers)
API key: AIzaSyB43pMEmHePuEpqxoSESxpLfUVq8lfz7AY
Referers: *twenty20investments.com

or

Key for server apps (with IP locking)
API key: AIzaSyCA16KV7uH6ZCUByJ6fXXM1nFPprt7-_X8
IPs: *twenty20investments.com

Is my use of the wild card correct?

Is my  code correctly used?

Has anyone else had this problem where the Maps application works fine but the error message is displayed when the page is first loaded?

Many thanks for some help here, this is now driving me mad.

Allan

Answer (score 0):

You've got 2 calls to the maps API in your page. Remove the first one which contains the incorrect key.

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=false&amp;key=ABQIAAAAPDUET0Qt7p2VcSk6JNU1sBSM5jMcmVqUpI7aqV44cW1cEECiThQYkcZUPRJn9vy_TWxWvuLoOfSFBw" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=3&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyB43pMEmHePuEpqxoSESxpLfUVq8lfz7AY" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, I saw this as well but do not know how to remove the second entry.  In the originating aspx page there is only one instance, when the code is compiled, the source is ripped out and packaged elsewhere (I think) leaving only the html code when one views the page's source.  I do not know what what is giving rise to the second entry,any ideas?  A header file elsewhere in the project?

Comment: Ah ha, found it.  There was a second entry in the master file page.  Let me try that, almost certainly this is the source of the problem.    Many thanks.

Comment: Great stuff - glad you found it :)